# Permission dialog for selecting images in external storage is not displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-11

I'm having a problem showing the Grant Permissions dialog. If I click on the ImageView, a dialog where the user can choose does not appear as intended, but I get to see the else branch within requestPermissionLauncher directly.
I use Android 11. According to the [description](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions), the dialog is no longer displayed from Android 11 if a user has denied permission more than once. How do I get it to display this anyway? I can't set READ_EXTERNAL_STORGAE in the settings
What am I doing wrong?

CreateShot.tk:

```
    bottomFilter.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.addImageToShot).setOnClickListener {
        when {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {

                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            }

            else -> {
                selectImage()
            }
        }
    }



private val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
             selectImage()
        } else {

            makeToast("Berechtigung nicht erteilt")
        }
    }
```

Manifest.xml:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

Comment: You do not need any permission to let the user select images. Where are you talking about?

Comment: I want to access the external storage to select images from there.  To do this I need the user's READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.  What else do I need this permission for?

Comment: No. Again: to let the user select images you do not need any permission. And why didnt you tell how you let the user select images. Where is your code?